# search query concatenation is not working

Tags: php

if condition is not working properly.
query gives result accurately.
i have 3 fields for searching
1. employee name
2. starting date
3. ending date

when i searched with all fields it works properly
when i searched with only date fields it also work properly
but when i searched with only Employee name field it doesn't work perhaps when i echo my query it work. but didn't show the result.

```
$query2 = "SELECT d.*, e.EMP_FIRST_NAME, a.ATTENDANCE_TYPE_TITLE
            FROM daily_sheet d 
            INNER JOIN attendance_type a ON a.ATTENDANCE_TYPE_ID = d.ATTENDANCE_TYPE_ID
            INNER JOIN ids_employ e ON e.EMP_ID = d.EMP_ID 

        WHERE 1 =1";
            if($ids_emp != '')
              {
                 $query2 .= " AND e.EMP_ID = '$ids_emp'";
              }       
              if($date1 != '' && $date2 != '')
              {
                $query2 .= " AND d.DATE >= '$date1' AND d.DATE <= '$date2'";
              } 
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2) or die("Selection Failed : " . mysqli_error());
$num2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
    $id = $row2["DAILY_SHEET_ID"];
    $emp_name = $row2["EMP_FIRST_NAME"];
    $username = $row2["USER_NAME"];
    $date = $row2["DATE"];
    $day = $row2["DAY"];
    $time_in = $row2["TIME_IN"];
    $time_out = $row2["TIME_OUT"];
    $attendance = $row2["ATTENDANCE_TYPE_TITLE"];
?>
```

Comment: what is the data type of `EMP_ID` ?

Comment: `where 1=1` is hacky.. you probably don't want to do that. Also, can you paste the exact string value of `query2` when the error occurs?

Comment: i already echo query and copy in mysql and execute..it gives result...but in application it not work

Comment: Does `it doesn't work` mean there's an error (share it) or that there are too many or too few results?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps:-

> 1) Print the query.
>
> 2) copy entire query.
>
> 3) open phpmyadmin
>
> 4) select your db
>
> 5) click on SQL section
>
> 6) paste query here and run it.

If there is any error then you will track it from there.

Comment: Requests should be in comments, since it is not an answer.

Comment: @Frederik: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
$ids_emp = '';
$date1  = '';
$date2  = '';

if ($ids_emp != '') {
$ids_emp_str = "AND `ids_emp`='" . $ids_emp . "'";
}
if($date1 != '' && $date2 != '')
{
$str2 = " AND d.DATE >= '$date1' AND d.DATE <= '$date2'";
 } 
 $sqlsearch = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE 1 = 1 $ids_emp_str $str2;
```

Enter Your real Fields and TRY this way.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

this 3 valible only understading for user

```
$ids_emp = "1";
$date1 = "2016/01/01";
$date2 = "2016/02/01";

$query2 = "SELECT d.*, e.EMP_FIRST_NAME, a.ATTENDANCE_TYPE_TITLE
            FROM daily_sheet d 
            INNER JOIN attendance_type a ON a.ATTENDANCE_TYPE_ID = d.ATTENDANCE_TYPE_ID
            INNER JOIN ids_employ e ON e.EMP_ID = d.EMP_ID  WHERE d.EMP_ID = 1";
            if($ids_emp != '')
              {
             $query2 .= " AND e.EMP_ID = '$ids_emp'";
              }       
              if($date1 != '' && $date2 != '')
              {
               $query2 .= " AND d.DATE >= '$date1' AND d.DATE <= '$date2'";
              }
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.